# Retrieving bitmap from internal memory fails on newer android versions

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am developing an android project with google maps and it has custom images for the markers of google map.But instead of downloading the images each time, the first time the marker images are downloaded into internal memory,  from the second time onwards i check if the images are downloaded and then they are retrieved from memory.

But the code works fine on my phone (Android version 2.6.3) , But when i tried on newer devices (Android 4 and above) the code for retrieving the downloaded bitmap image returns null.

The code for checking if the images have been downloaded:

```
public void checkcategoryimagesavailable() {
    path_file=MainActivity.this.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
    for(int i=0;i<catprearr.size();i++) {
        File file = new File(path_file+File.separator+catprearr.get(i)+".png");
        if(file.exists()) {

        } else {
            downloadfile(URL_image+catprearr.get(i)+".png",path_file+File.separator+catprearr.get(i)+".png");
        }
    }
    setvaluesonmap();
}
```

The code for downloading the images:

```
public void downloadfile(String path,String filepath) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(path);

        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        ucon.setReadTimeout(5000);
        ucon.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream inStream = new BufferedInputStream(is, 1024 * 5);
        File file = new File(filepath);
        file.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        byte[] buff = new byte[5 * 1024];

        int len;
        while ((len = inStream.read(buff)) != -1) {
            outStream.write(buff, 0, len);
        }

        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        inStream.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The code for setting the markers:

```
public void setvaluesonmap() {
    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {
        final Store_data s=list.get(i);

        Bitmap obj=getImageBitmap(MainActivity.this,s.category+".png");
        obj=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(obj,68,62,false);
        iv_category_logo.setImageBitmap(obj);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(s.store_name)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createDrawableFromView(MainActivity.this, custom_layout)))
            .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(s.store_latitude),Double.parseDouble(s.store_longitude))));
    }
}
```

The code for retrieving the downloaded image:**This is the troubled code:the bitmap returns null on newer devices**

```
public Bitmap getImageBitmap(Context context,String name) {
    try {
        // FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput(name);
        // File file = new File("filesdir", name);
        File myFile = new File (path_file+File.separator+name); 
        byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
        //fis.close();
        return b;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why does it work fine on older devices,But doesnt work on newer devices.